# Website renders differently on Mac Safari

Tags: html, css, safari

I am making a website in which everything is fine on almost all major browsers but somehow Mac Safari is showing a different css layout. like wrong background ( black-gray to white) wrong Nav-link color (white to default blue)

as I don't have Mac myself. I am not able to identify or test anything regarding this.

can you look at it & tell me if there is a solution or workaround it. [Website](http://www.jeremybennett.ca/JB/)
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looking ok on my safari.. http://imageshack.com/a/img22/8407/z9ag.png

Comment: Thanks for checking it... can you share a full "Mac book pro Safari" screenshot ... it will help me showing client the actual result.

he sent me this screenshot of Mac safari http://imageshack.com/a/img703/7867/xdkk.jpg

Comment: No offense but you should ask your client to send you a proper screenshot. This is an image not screenshot. Also ask him to clear his cache and reopen this website.

Comment: yeah...i know it's not clear at all...This was my first reaction to him ...and already asked to send a proper screenshot. I just took a step forward to identify problem as i found when searching that Mac safari is a sibling of IE ..gives a headache now & then..Thanks for giving it a look!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at it on my iMac (OSX 10.8.5, Safari 6.1.2), I see the dark gray background and white nav-link color. [Here's a screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mfDPZ.png)

I would suggest giving an emulator like BrowserStack a try if you don't have access to a mac. (I think there's a free trial account option.) I will also parrot Lokesh's comment to (nicely) remind your client to clear his cache and try again.

Also, I did notice you have a horizontal scrollbar no matter the browser window's width. I believe it is from the `width: 100%;` on your footer. Try `width: auto;` instead.

Hope that helps. Good luck with your client!

Comment: Thank you very much for giving ur valuable time like above experts..

I used browserstack to send a screenshot of it to client ...let's see what he says..

& thanks for the additional nice suggestion..gonna implement for sure.